# difference with google drive SDK installed application and web application

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm going to access with Google drive SDK. should I Create installed application configuration or  web application configuration in order to access API? what is the main difference?

Answer (score 0):

answer of difference is that:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#scenarios